# Removing old domain user files from local machine

Tags: windows, windows-xp, user-accounts, domain

How do I delete old domain user files from local machine. Like the ones in:

> C:\Users\Documents and Settings\

Because it will leave some stuff in the registry as well. Is there a proper way to delete a user and wipe out everything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on My Computer.  Click Properties.  Click the Advanced Tab.  Under User Profiles click Settings and then pick the account you want removed.  Click Delete.

That cleans things up pretty well.